# How to install behat and mink drivers in Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64, behat, mink

I am trying to set up mink to work with behat, using the instructions at http://mink.behat.org/.  As you will see, about 2 screens down it tells us that mink has been installed with no drivers. I think that means it can't talk to anything.

Then it gives a composer.json file for newbies to start with. I tried it, and when I run

```
php composer.phar install
```

this is what I get.

```
D:\Projects\TestCoachmaster>php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for behat/mink-zombie-driver * -> satisfiable by behat/mink-zombie-driver v1.0.0.
    - behat/mink-zombie-driver v1.0.0 requires symfony/process >=2.1.0,<2.2.0-dev -> no matching package found
.
  Problem 2
    - behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.0 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.3 requires fabpot/goutte @dev -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.2 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.*@dev -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.1 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.x-dev -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for behat/mink-goutte-driver * -> satisfiable by behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.1, b
ehat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.2, behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.3, behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.0.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting 
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

D:\Projects\TestCoachmaster>
```

I have tried tweaking the minimum-stability to dev, and that did not help.

I am running under windows 7, 64 bit - and I have had to do a LOT of tweaking to get bhat and mink to install. I do think they have - its the drives that haven't.

Help gratefully received. 
Ian

Answer (score 0):

I went through this same problem a few days ago. This is a minimum stability issue. I don´t know how you tried to set the minimum stability, but what you should do is:

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-selenium-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-zombie-driver": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev" 
}
```

This should work, I tried it right now. Notice that I removed the reference to behat/mink as this produced another error and it should be automatically found as a dependence of these drivers

Comment: When I try that, I get errors about the goutte-driver. Upon taking that out it did not complain, but it removed behat/behat and gerkin, leaving me without anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step guide to install behat on windows : [openguider.wordpress.com](http://openguider.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/how-to-install-behat-on-windows/)